# Accessing router from a command line

Tags: router

Is it possible to access a router and login from a command line ?

I'm well aware of

```
firefox 192.168.1.1
```

but are there parameters that can be added to this so that it's an immediate login from the browser, i know of telnet 192.168.1.1 but I'm looking for something a little more advanced to expand my knowledge.

Comment: What brand and model is the router? Some routers have `telnet` (or other) login capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very generic question that reveals little knowledge of how networked devices work.

The answer is, of course, it depends.

- Routers that provide command line services like telnet or SSH can be accessed using the respective protocols (`telnet <ip>` or `ssh <user>@<ip>`).
- Routers that do not provide command line management services cannot be accessed this way. There is usually a web based interface and that's it.
- There are also cases where a particular piece of software is required to interact with a device using some kind of more or less open protocol.
  If you go deeply into the hardware, you may also find a serial based console interface... but that's another story.

Comment: if using ssh especially on most commercial routers, you might find a message like: ```Unable to negotiate with 192.168.x.x port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc```  ,  In this case just add the cypher you want, ```ssh user@192.168.xx.xx -c {cypher}``` Cypher is aes128-cbc or any other shown by your router as an offer. This should allow negotiation and a user can login.

Answer (score 1):

Do you talk about bash? Please tag your question to know about the operating system.

What do you think about lynx:

http://lynx.invisible-island.net/

Lynx is a text web browser and should be provided by most linux package repostitories. Installation depends on your distribution (`sudo apt-get install lynx`, `sudo yum install lynx`, ...).

Because images should not be that important to manage a router via web page this could be useful for you.

If your router uses AUTH TYPE BASIC to authenticate the option '-auth' could be your friend. But if it has a form base login it will get more complicated - perhabs it is not possible.